# self.ParseError('String missing ending quote: %r' % (text,))

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling

I was making a custom object detector using Tensorflow's Object Detection API found in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection.

I am following tutorial https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

I am already training the model by running `train.py` using this command:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

However, I get this error: (just pasted the last line)

> File
>   "/Users/cvsanbuenaventura/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 1288, in _ConsumeSingleByteString
>       raise self.ParseError('String missing ending quote: %r' % (text,)) google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 123:17 : String missing ending
>   quote:
>   '"/Users/cvsanbuenaventura/Documents/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/train.record“'

Then I went to the `models/research/object_detection/training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`, which the tutorial mentioned to edit the necessary parts, such as changing the `PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/`.

In one line of the `PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED` to

```
/Users/cvsanbuenaventura/Documents/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/train.record
```

And here's the value of config params that I changed.

```
#Sample train_input_reader
train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "gs://vivienne-artifacts/object_detection_rat/data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "gs://vivienne-artifacts/object_detection_rat/data/labelmap.pbtxt"
}
```

which I think is the cause of the error. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure, the train.record is created without an error? It must be something to do with protobuf.

Comment: @user2906838 how can I know if there's an error? How do I fix it?

Comment: Well, can you please tell me, your tensorflow version, protobuf version, and show me the content of your pbtxt?

Comment: @user2906838 tensorflow version is 1.8.0, and this is the contents of my labelmap.pbtxt .     `item {
  id: 1
  name: ‘pedestrian’
}
`

Comment: @user2906838 how do I know my protobuf version?

Comment: you followed the installation https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md right? Did you make sure to compile the protocs?  `protoc --version` to check the protobuf-compiler version.

Comment: @user2906838 protoc version is 3.6.0, python version is 3.6.5

Comment: @user2906838 well I think so, I was following the tutorial that I mention above.

Comment: @user2906838 I issued this command `# From tensorflow/models/research/`

Comment: @user2906838     `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

Comment: did it work for you now?

Comment: @user2906838 still the same problem